# Dropdownlist combined value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to combine dropdownlist values from an entity.

Say I have a person class with Last Name and First Name

I have tried doing this:

```
ViewBag.uservalues = new SelectList(db.Persons, "ID", "FirstName" + " " + "LastName");
```

But this spits out an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from c in db.Persons
            select new { id = c.ID,Names = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName };

ViewBag.personid = new SelectList(query, "ID", "Names");
```

Comment: What does the View code look like?

Comment: `<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("personid",String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonID)
        </div>`

Comment: So you've got data in two different places, your ViewModel and the ViewBag?  I'll have to think about that.  It doesn't seem very clean.  Then again, it doesn't require any magic strings, so.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to the `SelectList` constructor

```
new SelectList(db.Persons,"ID", "FirstName"+" " + "LastName");
```

uses [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which requires the name of a public field or property in your `ViewModel` to bind to, and you probably don't have a field or property in your ViewModel named "FirstName LastName".

Add a property to your `ViewModel` class that concatenates the two fields (call it `FirstAndLastName`), and specify that property by name in your `SelectList` call.

```
new SelectList(db.Persons,"ID", "FirstAndLastName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the entity framework creates partial classes you should make another partial class in the same namespace that has the derived property that you want to use.

if the entity fraemwork created a class:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public String FirstName {get;set;}
    public String LastName{get;set;}
    public Int32 ID{get;set;}
}
```

create a new partial class

```
public partial class Person
{
    public String FullName {get{ return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName}}
}
```

and store it in another folder somewhere in your project (but with the same namespace)